# Aligning equations within a box in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am trying to get aligned equations within a box in rmarkdown. I am knitting to pdf.

The reason the box is necessary is because the YAML metadata I use automatically left-aligns all the text, but I want the equations centered.

Here is my rmarkdown code. As you can see when you run it, the equations are centered but the second set of `=` signs are not aligned across the two lines.

Any help much appreciated.

````
---
title: "Aligning equations in a box"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: null
  word_document: null
toc: yes
linestretch: 1.3
classoption: fleqn
header-includes: 
 - \setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
 - \setlength\parindent{0pt}
---


\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-15pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{1pt}

```{r global_options, include=FALSE, echo = FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8, fig.path='Figs/', 
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, dev = 'pdf')
```

These words are automatically left-aligned by the YAML meta-data above so a box is necessary to centre equations.

### Equation 11.6

\[\large
  \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
    \begin{aligned}
              \text{when}\ PT &= 0:logit\ h(t_{j})\ &= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}]\\
              \text{when}\ PT &= 1:logit\ h(t_{j})\ &= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}] + \beta_{1}
    \end{aligned}
  $}
\]
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but is it necessary to have a big space between? If not, you can just remove the `&`,

```
    \[\large
      \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
                  \text{when}\ PT =& 0:logit\ h(t_{j})\ = [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}]\\
                  \text{when}\ PT =& 1:logit\ h(t_{j})\ = [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}] + \beta_{1}
        \end{aligned}
      $}
    \]
```

this gives

[image]

If you want a space you could use something like `\qquad` or `\quad`

```
    \[\large
      \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
                  \text{when}\ PT =& 0:logit\ h(t_{j})\ \qquad= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}]\\
                  \text{when}\ PT =& 1:logit\ h(t_{j})\ \qquad= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}] + \beta_{1}
        \end{aligned}
      $}
    \]
```

which gives me

[image]

**EDIT:**

Answering the question in your comment. Wrap the blocks in between two `&`.

```
    \[\large
      \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
                  \text{whenmoretext}\ PT &= 0:logit\ h(t_{j})\ &  &= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}]\\
                  \text{when}\ PT &= 1:logit\ h(t_{j})\ &  &= [\alpha_{7}D_{7} + \alpha_{8}D_{8} + \cdots + \alpha_{12}D_{12}] + \beta_{1}
        \end{aligned}
      $}
    \]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @shituoshan. That works great, but isn't the `&` supposed to anchor the `=` and make them aligned across lines?

Comment: @llewmills yes it is, and that’s what you’re doing after `PT=` and break it off with ` \\ ` at the end of the line. This here works because `\text{when}\PT=& 0:logit` and `\text{when}\PT=1:logit` are the same length.

Comment: So @shitoushan how would I get the second set of equals signs to align if there was extra text before one of them (e.g. \text{whenthereismoretext} instead of just \text{when}?

Comment: Thank you. Very useful tip.